# JQM Gallery with swipe function for phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am searching for a nice image gallery plugin which supports swipe function in PhoneGap jQuery mobile. It should works similar to this http://www.tn3gallery.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not try it in PhoneGap, but i have implemented it on jquery mobile webpage:

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/